# Mac OS X : cannot restore mac by any recovery mode

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, time-machine

I fooled around and installed Kubuntu on my mac whipping out the HDD completely, but as not satisfied from the OS, I tried to return back to OSX. I had the most recent back-up but when I tried to re-install my MBP 9,1 using internet recovery, I cannot reinstall the OS using time machine as I faced an error on start stating :

> The disk can't be erased

later when I tried to restore the available mountain lion OS on my mac, the installation passes 75% through the process and gives out an error, which is not specified.

basically I think that the time machine of the "mac's internet recovery" is quiet old and thus is not able to install the back ups of the latest el-capitan OS..

any suggestions will be helpfull (and yes, I did check the system date and time before installation, they are correct).

I tried these things several times today but got the same results, please help me revive my MBP

Comment: Do you actually mean whipping out ie removing the disk or wiping out, i.e. erasing the disk? I assume the latter. Does your Time Machine drive have a current recovery partition? If so, booting from that should give you free-reign over the internal drive.

Comment: If you boot into the recovery partition, you must open the Disk Utillity to wipe the drive with another OS on it. To do this, you must click erase drive, and set it to HFS+. After this, you should be able to install the old OS.

Comment: 'master boot partition'?? What's that? You need to format GUID/HFS+ but to do that you cannot be booted from that drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry . Was incorrect. Forgot that's only on some external drives.

Comment: by whiping I mean erasing. and I do not think MBR is going to help, mac works on GPT I think

Comment: So, what you mean is, I use the the live stick of ubuntu and format the laptop HDD into GUID partition? Nice Idea, will try now and let you know